# Are there any suggestions to improve my code (without decorators)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is about a user trying to guess a number between 1 and 10

```py
from random import randint

answer = None
random_number = randint(1, 10)
```

The following block forces the user to enter an integer number and return its value

```py
def ask_int_number():
    try:
        num_guess = int(input("Pick a number from 1 to 10: ")) 
    except ValueError as err:
        num_guess = None
        print("You must enter an integer!")
        print(err)

    return num_guess
```

Checks if the number satisfies the game's conditions
1- number between 1 and 10
2- too low if smaller, too high if greater, correct if equal

```py
def check_number(guess):
    if num_guess in range(1, 11):
        if num_guess < random_number:
            print("Too low!")
            return False
        elif num_guess > random_number:
            print("Too high!")
            return False
        else:
            print("Correct!")
            return True
    elif type(num_guess) is int:
        print("Number must be between 1 and 10")

    return False
```

Checks if the user wishes to continue playing

```py
def check_answer():
    answer = input("Play again? Y/N\n")
    answer = answer[0].lower()
    if answer not in ("y", "n"):
        print("Please answer by 'Y' or 'N'")
        return False

    return answer
```

Function to run the game

```py
def run_game():
    while answer != "n":
        num_guess = ask_int_number()
        if not check_number(num_guess):
            continue
        answer = check_answer()
            if answer == "y":
            random_number = randint(1, 10)
```

```py
run_game()
```

Comment: Hello, I am new to programming. I am taking my second course on python. This is a simple number guessing game (from 1 to 10), and all is working well. However, I want to see if there are any tips or remarks regarding the structure of the program and the control flow. Thank you.

Comment: if your code is working and you want to improve its readability/performance -- then there is a special place for this called https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but in either way you need to provide description of what your code does

Comment: I hope the format is better now. I am new to programming and being active in the community.However, I shall learn about the standards with time. Thank you all for your messages and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are much cleaner ways to do it but here is a quick one:

```
import random

num = []


def ran_gen():
    global num
    for x in range(1):
        num = random.randrange(0, 10)
    number_guess()


def number_guess():
    print('''

    Guess a number between 1-10

    ''')
    while True:
        try:
            guess = int(input(':>  '))
            if guess == num:
                print('You guessed correct!')
                exit()
            if guess != num:
                print('That\'s not the number, guess again')
        except ValueError:
            print('That is not a number')


ran_gen()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your contribution was very insightful and helpful. It will definitely help me to improve my approach and how I structure my program. It is obvious that there is lots of code and conditions which I did not need to use. Thank you.